# Adobe Flash Builder 4.7 Not Installing

Tags: flash, installation, adobe, flash-builder, creative-cloud

I have recently been doing more Flash developing and I want to use the Adobe Flash Builder 4.7 Eclipse plugin.  The problem is, when I go to download Flash Builder from the Creative Cloud website, it launches an external protocol request to the Creative Cloud desktop application - like it should - but when the app starts up, nothing gets installed! It just sits there doing nothing! Furthermore, I can't install it directly from the Creative Cloud app because it isn't even in the list of apps to download! I have already researched this and nobody else seems to be having this problem.  Please help soon because I want to get developing!

Comment: You cannot install Flash Builder externally, only from the Adobe colud plugin running on your PC. Did it download the FB and then get stuck ? Or does it hang before attempting / while attempting to download ?

Comment: Starting the Creative cloud app as administrator might help. Also make sure you don't block any adobe sites in your hosts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to "Preferences.." in the Creative Cloud app, then the "Apps" tab under the "Creative Cloud" tab and select "Show Older Apps". You'll now see Flash Builder Premium listed in the main Apps menu.